# Installing swagger-ui

Tags: installation, install-from-source, client

I'd like to use [Swagger](http://swagger.wordnik.com/), the api-documentation tool on my Ubuntu 12.04 system. On a Windows machine I just open the *index.html* file with Firefox and put in the address that I want the swagger-ui to work with, but on Ubuntu it seems like it isn't working properly - I can see that the Swagger-ui isn't even trying to fetch the resources page.

Has anyone succeeded in doing this? Did you install coffeescript and handlebars, or do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if firefox can open file-based resources then there shouldn't be an issue.  I'd suggest the following:

- Use the pre-built distribution from here: https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui/downloads  Otherwise you'll need to follow the instructions to build it from scratch, since the source uses coffeescript, etc.
- Open the network panel to see if there are requests to external resources.  If you're hosting the swagger-based json files on a web server, or using server integration to create them automatically, you might need to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` as described here: https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/java-jax-rs
- Look in the console output to see if there is any javascript error emitted from reading an invalid spec file

You shouldn't need to install coffeescript or handlebars to run the UI, only build it.

Comment: I didn't download the build, I downloaded the sources. Your link to the pre-built distribution works fine.

Comment: great, unfortunately github has deprecated the download feature, so we're going to have to distribute the distribution a different way